# Applications starting but not showing UI

Tags: windows-7, crash, alt-tab, application-launch

I tried to start applications as usual from the Windows start menu. Over ~ 30 minutes, I got the following effects:

- applications with a GUI do not get shown any more.
- I can continue using GUI applications that are already opened
- I can open non-GUI / console applications (like `cmd`).
- From the command line prompt, I can see that the GUI applications are started using `tasklist`

Here's an example:

```
>tasklist | find "taskmgr"
taskmgr.exe                   4352 Console                    1      7.216 K
taskmgr.exe                   7824 Console                    1      7.216 K
taskmgr.exe                   7232 Console                    1      7.232 K
```

As you can imagine, I tried to start Task Manager to diagnose the problem 3 times. But none of the Task Manager windows became visible.

Under the assumption that `tasklist` displays the processes in the order they were started, I roughly identified the issue:

```
...
openAgent.exe                 7012 Console                    1    592.440 K Not Responding
...
WerFault.exe                  3592 Console                    1     10.112 K Unknown
...
```

`openAgent` is an application I closed (or at least tried to close, since it still seems to be running). Something must have crashed due to the presence of `WerFault`, but I could not see a Windows Error Reporting dialog.

Terminating the `openAgent` application forcefully using `taskkill /pid 7012 /f`, all applications I attempted to start suddenly appeared.

Looking at the Windows Error Reporting dialog now, it shows exception `80000003`, which is a (debug) breakpoint.

**What has happened here? I'd like to understand the situation from a Windows Internals standpoint.** In theory I'd expect that the crash of a user mode application should not be able to influence other applications.

Unfortunately I neither have a kernel dump of the situation nor a user mode crash dump of `openAgent`, so this is all information I can give you.

My system is Windows 7 SP1 x64 Enterprise, no pending Windows updates, Intel Core i7 CPU. `openAgent` is an executable of SilkTest by MicroFocus, a test automation tool.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to explain what happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue once again and it turns out that `openAgent` installs a hook called `OsHookDll_x86` from the same company.

This hook applies to `DispatchHookW()`:

```
2:010> k
...
0049f2b0 75a86381 OsHookDll_x86!GetMessageHook+0x37
0049f2cc 75a780a9 USER32!DispatchHookW+0x38
...
0049f544 5eff5709 USER32!PeekMessageW+0x108
```

which affects the Windows Message loop. The windows message loop is needed by any GUI application to run.

The hook sends Windows Messages to `openAgent` via `USER32!SendMessageW()` but `openAgent` was suspended by Windows Error Reporting (`WerFault`) and therefore cannot process such messages, resulting in a timeout:

```
1:009> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
00138f90 75a79886 USER32!NtUserMessageCall+0x15
00138fcc 75a797f3 USER32!SendMessageTimeoutWorker+0xa6
00138ff4 59d6066c USER32!SendMessageTimeoutW+0x21
...
```

I could not fully analyze the rest since during my debug session, everything else started to freeze as well. I assume that the hook tries to resend the message instead of returning, thus resulting in an endless loop.

`!analyze -v` did not work due to [Missing symbols for `ntdll`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32217038/ntdll-module-not-loading-correctly-in-windbg-but-why).